# What is the relationship between Luminosity, Intensity, and Flux?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, large-hadron-collider, scattering, luminosity

I am always confused by the terminology:

In high energy particle scattering, and in particular, in the context of collider physics, what is the relationship between [luminosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity#Scattering_theory), [intensity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_%28physics%29) and [flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux)?  What are the (SI *and* natural) units for these quantities?  And finally, how do they relate to the cross section and to the event rate?

There are so many quantities to keep track of--I think it's easy to get lost!!

Comment: Well... it looks like the wiki links that Qmechanic added to my question almost answers my question (especially the 'luminosity' link).  I guess all that is left now is how to relate flux to the other two...